# discord.Embed returned from user-defined functions cannot be sent

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I was trying to make my own custom help command

main.py (get_prefix is another function I defined, but that shouldn't be the problem):

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = get_prefix, case_insensitive = True, intents = discord.Intents.all())
bot.remove_command("help") # remove the default help command to add a custom one

@bot.group(invoke_without_command = True) # custom help command
async def help(ctx):
    await ctx.send(await help_embed(ctx.message))
```

customhelp.py:

```
import discord
import typing

async def create_help(cmd: str, desc: str, syntax: typing.List[str], prefix: str, examples: typing.List[str] = None, thumbnail_url: str = None, fields: typing.Dict[str, str] = None):
    embed = discord.Embed(title = cmd, description = desc, color = discord.Color.random())
    embed.set_thumbnail(url = thumbnail_url)
    embed.add_field(name = "syntax", value = f"`{prefix}{syntax}`")
    
    if examples is not None:
        example_str = ""
        for ex in examples:
            example_str += f"\n`{prefix}{ex}`"
        embed.add_field(name = "examples", value = example_str[1:])

    if fields is not None:
        for field in fields:
            embed.add_field(name = field, value = fields[field])
        
    return embed

async def help_embed(prefix: str):
    return await create_help("help", f"This is a list of all commands. For more details of each command type `{prefix}help <command>`", ["help", "help <command>"], prefix, thumbnail_url = "https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000378178157-omlzp3-t500x500.jpg")
```

but then when I tested it out on discord my bot sent this:
`<discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x7f1552033820>`

What is the cause of this problem? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with how you are using the `ctx.send()` method, the definition of this method (from the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=send#discord.TextChannel.send)) is

```
await send(content=None, *, tts=False, embed=None, file=None, files=None, delete_after=None, nonce=None, allowed_mentions=None, reference=None, mention_author=None)
```

As you can see, what you are currently passing to the command is only the `content` variable, which is typically what the bot will send, but you are passing to it a `discord.embeds.Embed` object (returned from the `help_embed()` and `create_help` functions. `content` is expecting to be a string, so that's why you see that as your output, it's just printing the object itself.

Now, what you are looking for is to send an embed, to do so, you will need to specify it in the `send()` command:

```
@bot.group(invoke_without_command = True) # custom help command
async def help(ctx):
    await ctx.send(embed = await help_embed(ctx.message))
```